# what's the difference between block__element__element and block__element-element in BEM

Tags: html, css, sass, bem

For example:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu__item">
        <div class="menu__item-title">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There's some solution like `menu__title`.

But if menu has its own title, then how to recognize menu's title and menu item's title?

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that `block__element__element` is not a valid BEM selector. The markup you showed in your question is the CORRECT way of naming your elements.

> **Create a block**
>
> If a section of code might be reused and it doesn't depend on other
>   page components being implemented.
>
> ---
>
> **Create an element**
>
> If a section of code can't be used separately without the parent
>   entity (the block).
>
> The exception is elements that must be divided into smaller parts –
>   subelements – in order to simplify development. In the BEM
>   methodology, you can't create elements of elements. In a case like
>   this, instead of creating an element, you need to create a service
>   block.

More info in the official documentation: https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#should-i-create-a-block-or-an-element

If you want to have Menu title, the markup should look something like this:

```
<div class="menu">
    <h2 class="menu__title">..</h2>
    <div class="menu__item">
        <div class="menu__item-title">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

BEM gets a bit tricky when you have "children" of an element. But either use the `menu__item-title` naming convention or rethink your element, perhaps it can be separated and reused as a **Block**?

Comment: I have seen BEM QA.But I didn't seen the essential difference.
I can also read Dom structure from menu__item-title.
And it's more difficult to see that menu__item-title is a child of menu__item in BEM name convention, because __ present the element but - not.
But I think menu__item-title looks more cleaner and elegant.
So if i want, i can use menu__item__title to replace menu__item-title?

Comment: Technically, you can, but still `menu__item__title` is not valid :) There are plenty variations of BEM out there, just choose one or make your own and be consistent with it.

Comment: @liajoy You could create a sub-block `.menu-item`, then `.menu-item__title` will be the child of its block.

Comment: @NikolayMihaylov So the reason not use menu__item__title is BEM name convention not support it. menu__item-title is just a plan b. right?

Comment: @NikolayMihaylov can i place menu__item-title anywhere even if it's out of menu__item but under menu? it can't be shown correctly.

Comment: @liajoy Question 1: Its plan A :) Question 2: Yes you can, thats the main idea of BEM. Old school selectors like `div h2 a` forces you to have the link inside the heading, but when moving it outside you are loosing styles.